# Construct Public Key from Big Integers?

Tags: java, c#-4.0, cryptography, rsa

I would like construct a public key which is constructed using C# XML RSAKeys, however I would like to reconstruct it using java, The problem is I receive the M & E themselves from the Key as bytes values, and to construct the key I've to use two BigIntegers, How do I construct the public key ?

Edit: The problem is the mod, exp byte arrays that was base64 decoded, are the M,N of the Public Key...

```
    byte[] mod  = Base64.decodeBase64(modulus.getBytes());
    byte[] exp  = Base64.decodeBase64(exponent.getBytes());

    int[] copyMod = new int[mod.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < mod.length; x++) {
        copyMod[x] = unsignedToBytes((byte) mod[x]);
    }

    int[] copyExp = new int[exp.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < exp.length; x++) {
        copyExp[x] = unsignedToBytes((byte) exp[x]);
    }

    String Mod =  Arrays.toString(copyMod);
    String Exp = Arrays.toString(copyExp);

    BigInteger m = new BigInteger(Mod.getBytes());
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger(Exp.getBytes());

        java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you tell us, what class you want to feed with the information.

Comment: Oh he could tell us, but then he'd have to kill us.  Get it?  He's working on an RSA application.  So it's like really secret.  Never mind...

Comment: @SteveJ The problem is the m,n which I got from a base64 decoder, they come in byte arrays, and to create a public key I should convert those two arrays to Bigintegers, which is a wrong operarion...

Comment: Ahmed, I was making a lame joke.  I'll give this some thought, though I think the answers given show some people are quite knowledgeable about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us what object type you want. But if you want an RSA public key, you can do (BouncyCastle):

```
RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = new JCERSAPublicKey(
    new RSAKeyParameters(false, modulus, exponent));
```

See the [class definition](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=public%5C%20class%5C%20JCERSAPublicKey%20lang%3ajava&type=cs).

Answer (score 1):

```
java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

Comment: That won't give you the key, you'll have to feed it to a key factory (you can also pass it to bouncycastle's JCERSAPublicKey constructor).

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll edit my answer. What's up with BountyCastle, though? The JRE comes with RSA support bundled. No need for any external library.

Comment: Sure, but for programs that heavily use cryptography, bouncycastle will help a lot, even if it's just for the JCA helpers.

Comment: The problem is the m,n which I got from a base64 decoder, they come in byte arrays, and to create a public key I should convert those two arrays to Bigintegers, which is a wrong operarion...

Comment: That was not obvious from your question. How is the XML file containing the public key created in C#? Without knowing that, it's impossible to know how to reconstruct the key from the XML. You should add the C# tag to your question and be more explicit about the way the XML file is built.

Comment: @JBNizet 
The public key is saved as an XML, for example <RSAKEY><Modulus> <Exponent>....

Comment: Yes, but there are several ways to encode a BigInteger object as a stream of characters. Show us the C# code that takes the equivalent of BigInteger as input, and returns the XML string as output.